# Is using an ORM and LINQ architecturally unsound?

Tags: linq, t-sql, architecture, orm, telerik

I'm currently using Telerik Open Access which is hateful, but that said is there not an architectural issue around the use of LINQ and ORMs in general?

It occurs to me that what we are doing is moving the burden of data manipulation from the DBMS which is optimised to  perform that task to in my case a webserver which is not.

Also, at least in Telerik's case we are restricting the flexibility of our coding model. In this project I have to extract and create complex data structures that do not map directly into a CRUD interface. 
In Telerik Open Access at least, if I use a stored procedure to create the data and it does not map into a known entity I have to return the data as an object array.

So instead I use the "entities" created by the ORM and manipulate them using LINQ. 
The resulting code is ridiculously complex compared to the relatively simple equivalent SQL statement.

I'd be interested in your views specifically around the advocacy of using an ORM and LINQ and whether this is architecturally unsound.

It certainly feels it to me.

I haven't included code samples because the actual code is irrelevant. That said it might be instructive to know that a 10 line T-SQL query (6 of those lines are joins) has turned into 300 lines (including whitespace) of LINQ statements to do the same thing.

Comment: i dont agree that 10 lines of T-Sql turns 300 lines of LINQ statements.

Comment: That's a very sweeping, baiting question, so be prepared for downvotes. The obvious answer is "yes, it's fine" since thousands of very capable developers use LINQ to SQL and the Entity Object Framework. A more useful question might be "Here are 10 lines of T-SQL. How can I succinctly write this as a LINQ query?" The answer will probably be 10 lines or less of C#.

Comment: If Telerik Open Access is "hateful" because of lousy stored procedure support, how would that put all ORMs under suspicion? Using linq-to-entities or linq-to-sql _without_ linq is architecturally unsound. How is OA's linq support? You don't mention the word "projection" which could (should) be the way to create "complex structures" with concise linq statements.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Linq2SQL or Linq2Entities they will actually generate SQL code and the "burden of data manipulation" will still be on the DBMS. The Linq code you write will be very much like SQL code in size.

Answer (score 1):

Using Linq in addition to an ORM isn't architecturally unsound.

You always have some amount of data manipulation on the database side and some amount on the client side. As a developer, it is yours to find the right balance. Obviously, if your ORM obliges you to do such convoluted things as manipulating a jumble of untyped data on the client side and doing massive queries on it with Linq, there's a problem. Either with your ORM or the way your system was designed.